# -7008 error in sqlrpgle even though commitment control is set to *NONE

Tags: db2, rpgle

I have an SQLRPGLE program that performs a delete operation using exec sql. The problem is I get an sqlcod of -7008 even though I have compiled the program with commit set to *NONE and also, I tried adding "with none" at end of the statement but nothing just seems to work.

Any ideas what can be done here?

**Update:**

So, the issue seems to be coming up because the tables I am trying to delete from seems to be parent tables which have a dependent table.

But what is confusing to me is, the dependent table is already cleared and it does not have any data. So why would it error?

```
Parent table :
  create table grid_details                               
    (id integer not null generated always as identity       
        (start with 1 increment by 1) 
        PRIMARY KEY,              
    grid_name varchar(20),                                  
    grid_description varchar(40),                           
    source_file_name varchar(30),                           
    created_date date default current_date,                 
    created_by varchar(30),                                 
    last_updated_date date default current_date,            
    updated_by varchar(30));     

Parent table :                               
  create table action_code_details
    (id integer not null generated always as                                    
        identity (start with 1 increment by 1)                 
        PRIMARY KEY,
    action_code varchar(10),                   
    action_description varchar(40),
    required_input clob,    
    end_point clob,
    created_date                            
    date default current_date,
    created_by varchar(30),      
    last_updated_date date default current_date,
    updated_by varchar(30));                  

Child table :
  create table grid_action_details
    (id integer not null                 
        generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1)                                        
        PRIMARY KEY,
    grid_details_id integer,
    foreign key(grid_details_id) references grid_details(id),
    action_code_details_id integer,          
    foreign key(action_code_details_id) references action_code_details(id),
    action_code_status varchar(2),    
    created_date date default                                            
    current_date,
    created_by varchar(30),                                 
    last_updated_date date default current_date,
    updated_by varchar(30),
    required_parameter clob);
```

I am able to delete everything from the child table but not from the parent table.

I found this when I tried to clear the parent tables through a CLRPFM. I don't understand this as the child table has no data. So why would the parent tables not get cleared?

Answer (score 1):

What reason code are you getting?  Should be returned as part of the [message text](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzala/rzalaml.htm#messages__SQL7008).

> Reason codes are:
>
> 1. -- &1 has no members.
> 2. -- &1 has been saved with storage free.
> 3. -- &1 not journaled, no authority to the journal, or the journal state is *STANDBY. Files with an RI constraint action of CASCADE, SET
>    NULL, or SET DEFAULT must be journaled to the same journal.
> 4. and 5
> 5. -- &1 is in or being created into production library but the user has debug mode UPDPROD(*NO).
> 6. -- Schema being created, but user in debug mode with UPDPROD(*NO).
> 7. -- A based-on table used in creation of a view is not valid. Either the table is program described table or it is in a temporary
>    schema.
> 8. -- Based-on table resides in a different ASP than ASP of object being created.
> 9. -- Index is currently held or is not valid.
> 10. -- A constraint or trigger is being added to an invalid type of table, or the maximum number of triggers has been reached, or all
>     nodes of the distributed table are not at the same release level.
> 11. -- Distributed table is being created in schema QTEMP, or a view is being created over more than one distributed table.
> 12. -- Table could not be created in QTEMP, QSYS, QSYS2, or SYSIBM because it contains a column of type DATALINK having the FILE LINK
>     CONTROL option.
> 13. -- The table contains a DATALINK, LOB, or XML column that conflicts with the data dictionary.
> 14. -- A DATALINK, LOB, XML, or IDENTITY column cannot be added to a non SQL table.
> 15. -- Attempted to create or change an object using a commitment definition in a different ASP.
> 16. -- Sequence &1 in &2 was incorrectly modified with a CL command.
> 17. -- The table is not usable because it contains partial transactions.

**EDIT**
So the correction for reason code 3 is

> Start journaling on &1 (STRJRNPF), get access to the journal, or
> change the journal state to *ACTIVE (CHGJRN).

Now normally, that code is thrown when you try to use commitment control and the file is not journaled.  But you mention that you've compiled with commit(*NONE) and that you've even added `with none` to your statement.  Thus, the problem likely lies the fact that the table is journaled and the journal state is *STANDBY.  I don't believe there'd be an authority issue with the journal itself.

**EDIT2**
Actually, taking a look at *STANDBY

> *STANDBY Most journal entries are not deposited into the journal. If an attempt is made to deposit an entry into the journal, there will be
> no errors indicating that the entry was not deposited. While in
> *STANDBY state, journaling can be started or stopped. However, using commitment control is not allowed while in *STANDBY state. Because
> commitment control is not allowed, functions where the system uses
> commitment control internally are also not allowed. Similarly, access
> paths built over files journaled to a journal in *STANDBY state will
> not be eligible for System-Managed Access Path Protection (SMAPP).
> This may impact system performance, system IPL, or independent
> auxiliary storage pool (IASP) vary-on duration, or both system
> performance and IPL or vary-on duration, as the system tries to
> achieve the specified access path recovery time. Note: This value
> cannot be specified for remote journals.

It doesn't seem that it should be a problem with a `DELETE` unless commitment control is being used or unless the file has a RI constraint  with an action of CASCADE, SET NULL, or SET DEFAULT.

Comment: The reason code is 3. And as I just noticed, the delete fails in STRSQL as well.

Comment: @theju112t see edit

Comment: kindly see updated question

Comment: See edit 2, basically comes down to the fact you need journaling when using RI.  So make sure all the table are journaled to the same journal.